# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY","message":"insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: apex, community, permissions, contentdocument

I have below apex method code which is executed by community guest users for the public-facing website.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.myVFPage;
    ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
            conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; 
            conVer.PathOnClient = PDF_TITLE_EXT; 
            conVer.Title = PDF_TITLE; 
            conVer.VersionData = pageRef.getContentAsPdf();
            conVer.Origin = 'H';
            insert conVer;
```

Above works fine and save the file under-owned by me tab as shown in the below image

[image]

now I need to display this file so creating a content distribution record

```
ContentDistribution contentDist              = new ContentDistribution();
        contentDist.Name                             = 'customName';
        contentDist.ContentVersionId                 = contentVersionId;
        contentDist.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser    = true;
        contentDist.PreferencesLinkLatestVersion     = true;
        contentDist.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit         = false;
        contentDist.PreferencesPasswordRequired      = false;
        contentDist.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = true;
insert contentDist;
```

executing above code as site guest user gives below error

> {"status":500,"body":{"fieldErrors":{},"pageErrors":[{"statusCode":"INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY","message":"insufficient
> access rights on cross-reference
> id"}],"index":null,"duplicateResults":[]},"headers":{}}

I have tried creating content document link

```
ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name =:accountName]?.id;
        conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDocId;  //ContentDocumentId Id from ContentVersion
        conDocLink.shareType = 'V';
        conDocLink.visibility = 'AllUsers';
        insert conDocLink;
```

it inserts content link but inserting content distribution still gives the same error

Beow are my content delivery settings.

[image]

Below are my author permission

[image]

Could someone please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Is apex code executed via lwc component or vf page?

Comment: Also owned by me there is it your user?

Comment: lwc component calling the vf controller, yes it is my user and any content version I create from  guest user showing under own by me (I am system administrator)

Comment: and also I am the default owner of the records created by guest users.

Comment: Are you creating the records in guest user context from incognito browser?

Comment: yes, first create content version record and then try to create distribution record and on distribution, it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127173/discussion-between-gs650x-and-mohith-shrivastava).

Comment: GuesUser has Acces to upload files ?  Allow site guest users to upload files is enabled ?

Answer (score 1):

I think one[image] thing missing is adding a user as Author in Library. Go to Files > Library > Manage Members > Add user as Author. [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but whatever guest user add to files shows under owned by me not under asset library, could you please tell me what should I do so that content version show under assest library instead of owned by me?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/237844/how-to-upload-a-file-to-a-specific-library-folder-using-apex

Comment: Actually, I have tried that but when I query content workspace as system admin I get the results but when I query workspace as guest user, it throws exception that list has now row to assign to sObject

Comment: I also tried by hard coding the workspace id of asset library now it throws insufficient access issue  while inserting content document link record.

Answer (score 0):

@gs650x
I have the same problem as you, according to my research, guest users can't create public link(ContentDistribution) since winter'19. Is that correct?
Do you have a solution for this problem?